# Parse a csv file to remove unwanted columns and double quotes

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have a multiple csv files which contain data like below. These csv files are written to every hour with new info. I am using filebeat to feed these to a logstash server, but want to configure the logstash conf file to parse the csv files.

`"Record Type","Record Code","Broker Name","Broker UUID","EG Name","EG UUID","Message Flow Name","Message Flow UUID","Application Name","Application UUID","Library Name","Library UUID","Record Start Date","Record Start Time","Record GMT Start Timestamp","Record End Date","Record End Time","Record GMT End Timestamp","Total Elapsed Time","Average Elapsed Time","Maximum Elapsed Time","Minimum Elapsed Time","Total CPU Time","Average CPU Time","Maximum CPU Time","Minimum CPU Time","CPU Time Waiting for Input Messages","Elapsed Time Waiting for Input Messages","Total Number of Input Messages","Total Size of Input Messages","Average Size of Input Messages","Maximum Size of Input Messages","Minimum Size of Input Messages","Number of Threads in Pool","Time Maximum Number of Threads reached","Total Number of MQ Errors","Total Number of Messages with Errors","Total Number of Errors Processing Messages","Total Number of Time Outs Waiting for Replies to Aggregate Messages","Total Number of Commits","Total Number of Backouts","Accounting Origin"
"Archive","Major Interval","DEV1","f328c29c-c695-11e5-addb-cc355a180000","PayoffQuote","9c276fa8-5201-0000-0080-941e766a88ad","com.payoffquote.PayOffQuote","273f59b2-5201-0000-0080-9c722b3eca55","","","","","2017-02-16","00:52:31.599941","2017-02-16 06:52:31.5999","2017-02-16","01:46:17.773842","2017-02-16 07:46:17.7738","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","183935","3226073825","0","0","0","0","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","Anonymous"
"Archive","Major Interval","DEV1","f328c29c-c695-11e5-addb-cc355a180000","PayoffQuote","9c276fa8-5201-0000-0080-941e766a88ad","com.payoffquote.PayOffQuote","273f59b2-5201-0000-0080-9c722b3eca55","","","","","2017-02-16","01:46:17.773949","2017-02-16 07:46:17.7739","2017-02-16","02:46:19.453657","2017-02-16 08:46:19.4536","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","193549","3601568195","0","0","0","0","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","Anonymous"
"Archive","Major Interval","DEV1","f328c29c-c695-11e5-addb-cc355a180000","PayoffQuote","9c276fa8-5201-0000-0080-941e766a88ad","com.payoffquote.PayOffQuote","273f59b2-5201-0000-0080-9c722b3eca55","","","","","2017-02-16","02:46:19.453716","2017-02-16 08:46:19.4537","2017-02-16","03:46:21.184574","2017-02-16 09:46:21.1845","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","201382","3601616866","0","0","0","0","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","Anonymous"
"Archive","Major Interval","DEV1","f328c29c-c695-11e5-addb-cc355a180000","PayoffQuote","9c276fa8-5201-0000-0080-941e766a88ad","com.payoffquote.PayOffQuote","273f59b2-5201-0000-0080-9c722b3eca55","","","","","2017-02-16","03:46:21.184637","2017-02-16 09:46:21.1846","2017-02-16","04:46:22.285130","2017-02-16 10:46:22.2851","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","216962","3600985884","0","0","0","0","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","Anonymous"
"Archive","Major Interval","DEV1","f328c29c-c695-11e5-addb-cc355a180000","PayoffQuote","9c276fa8-5201-0000-0080-941e766a88ad","com.payoffquote.PayOffQuote","273f59b2-5201-0000-0080-9c722b3eca55","","","","","2017-02-16","04:46:22.285240","2017-02-16 10:46:22.2852","2017-02-16","05:46:18.761927","2017-02-16 11:46:18.7619","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","211619","3596362373","0","0","0","0","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","Anonymous"
"Archive","Major Interval","DEV1","f328c29c-c695-11e5-addb-cc355a180000","PayoffQuote","9c276fa8-5201-0000-0080-941e766a88ad","com.payoffquote.PayOffQuote","273f59b2-5201-0000-0080-9c722b3eca55","","","","","2017-02-16","05:46:18.762035","2017-02-16 11:46:18.7620","2017-02-16","06:46:19.935240","2017-02-16 12:46:19.9352","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","230385","3601047136","0","0","0","0","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","Anonymous"
"Archive","Major Interval","DEV1","f328c29c-c695-11e5-addb-cc355a180000","PayoffQuote","9c276fa8-5201-0000-0080-941e766a88ad","com.payoffquote.PayOffQuote","273f59b2-5201-0000-0080-9c722b3eca55","","","","","2017-02-16","06:46:19.935316","2017-02-16 12:46:19.9353","2017-02-16","07:46:21.328939","2017-02-16 13:46:21.3289","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","231875","3601265537","0","0","0","0","0","1","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","Anonymous"`

No I want to parse these files to get the following

`timestamp: 2017-02-16 00:52:31 broker: DEV1 eg_name: PayoffQuote message_flow_name: com.payoffquote.PayOffQuote input_messages: 0 cpu_time: 0
timestamp: 2017-02-16 01:46:17 broker: DEV1 eg_name: PayoffQuote message_flow_name: com.payoffquote.PayOffQuote input_messages: 0 cpu_time: 0
timestamp: 2017-02-16 02:46:19 broker: DEV1 eg_name: PayoffQuote message_flow_name: com.payoffquote.PayOffQuote input_messages: 0 cpu_time: 0
timestamp: 2017-02-16 03:46:21 broker: DEV1 eg_name: PayoffQuote message_flow_name: com.payoffquote.PayOffQuote input_messages: 0 cpu_time: 0
timestamp: 2017-02-16 04:46:22 broker: DEV1 eg_name: PayoffQuote message_flow_name: com.payoffquote.PayOffQuote input_messages: 0 cpu_time: 0
timestamp: 2017-02-16 05:46:18 broker: DEV1 eg_name: PayoffQuote message_flow_name: com.payoffquote.PayOffQuote input_messages: 0 cpu_time: 0
timestamp: 2017-02-16 06:46:19 broker: DEV1 eg_name: PayoffQuote message_flow_name: com.payoffquote.PayOffQuote input_messages: 0 cpu_time: 0`

I have used the csv filter to get the following

`{"Message Flow Name":"com.payoffquote.PayOffQuote","Total CPU Time":"0","Record Start Date":"2017-02-16","Total Number of Input Messages":"0","Broker Name":"DEV1","Record Start Time":"00:52:31.599941","timestamp":"2017-02-16:00:52:31.599941"}
{"Message Flow Name":"com.payoffquote.PayOffQuote","Total CPU Time":"0","Record Start Date":"2017-02-16","Total Number of Input Messages":"0","Broker Name":"DEV1","Record Start Time":"01:46:17.773949","timestamp":"2017-02-16:01:46:17.773949"}
{"Message Flow Name":"com.payoffquote.PayOffQuote","Total CPU Time":"0","Record Start Date":"2017-02-16","Total Number of Input Messages":"0","Broker Name":"DEV1","Record Start Time":"02:46:19.453716","timestamp":"2017-02-16:02:46:19.453716"}
{"Message Flow Name":"com.payoffquote.PayOffQuote","Total CPU Time":"0","Record Start Date":"2017-02-16","Total Number of Input Messages":"0","Broker Name":"DEV1","Record Start Time":"03:46:21.184637","timestamp":"2017-02-16:03:46:21.184637"}
{"Message Flow Name":"com.payoffquote.PayOffQuote","Total CPU Time":"0","Record Start Date":"2017-02-16","Total Number of Input Messages":"0","Broker Name":"DEV1","Record Start Time":"04:46:22.285240","timestamp":"2017-02-16:04:46:22.285240"}
{"Message Flow Name":"com.payoffquote.PayOffQuote","Total CPU Time":"0","Record Start Date":"2017-02-16","Total Number of Input Messages":"0","Broker Name":"DEV1","Record Start Time":"05:46:18.762035","timestamp":"2017-02-16:05:46:18.762035"}
{"Message Flow Name":"com.payoffquote.PayOffQuote","Total CPU Time":"0","Record Start Date":"2017-02-16","Total Number of Input Messages":"0","Broker Name":"DEV1","Record Start Time":"06:46:19.935316","timestamp":"2017-02-16:06:46:19.935316"}`

But i have issues removing the double quotes and changing them to lower cases.
Can you please tell me if I can use grok to get the output as desired?
`timestamp: 2017-02-16 00:52:31 broker: DEV1 eg_name: PayoffQuote message_flow_name: com.payoffquote.PayOffQuote input_messages: 0 cpu_time: 0
......so on`

Answer (score 0):

Grok doesn't really do replacements, merely extracting strings to fill in fields. Where I suspect you'll get more joy [is with the `mutate` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html). Use in combination with grok to get what you're looking for.

```
mutate {
  gsub -> [ 
    "message_flow_name", " ", "_"
  ]
  lowercase => [ "message_flow_name" ]
}
```

Which will replace spaces with underscores in the field-data, and then lowercase it.

However, if you're trying to get your field *names* lower-cased and underscored, it will take more work and I don't know of a way to iterate over the fields without resorting to the `ruby {}` filter. That leaves the brute-force method. Not pretty.

```
mutate {
  rename => {
    "Message Flow Name" => "message_flow_name"
    "Input Message"     => "input_message"
    [...]
    "Accounting Origin" => "accounting_origin"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yup.I did use mutate to rename the columns i wanted. But i am currently doing it with filter csv. If i had to do it with grok how would i extract the columns?